# Get output of a Powershell job registered with Register-ObjectEvent

Tags: powershell

I've got this script which is executing but not returning the output.

```
function code-Build-RepoWeb
{
     $job = Start-Job { code-Build-Component RepoWeb; Start-Sleep -seconds 5 }

     Register-ObjectEvent $job -EventName StateChanged `
    -SourceIdentifier JobStateChanged `
    -Action {$jobInfo = Receive-Job -Keep $Sender; Write-Host $jobInfo }
 }
```

I am not an expert with Powershell, and read some doc before asking the question.

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you should just use `Wait-Job` rather than listen for events. `Wait-Job` first, then `$job` will be done and you can use `Receive-Job`.

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to register for events, here's how you can do it:

```
 Start-Job { ... } | Wait-Job | Receive-Job -Keep
```

In case you need a non-blocking command. This will create a global variable to hold the results of the job:

```
$job = Start-Job { Start-Sleep -Seconds 5; 1..5 }

$null = Register-ObjectEvent $job -EventName StateChanged -SourceIdentifier JobEnd -Action {

    if($sender.State -eq 'Completed')
    {
        $global:jobInfo = Receive-Job $job        
    } 
}   

$jobInfo
```

Comment: Yep, exactly this. `-keep` is optional.

Comment: Don't forget to `Remove-Job` after it's finished.

Comment: Forgot to say that this call have to be non-blocking that's why I was registering the event.